# Include a component as part of a plugin

Tags: aurelia

## Initial Question

How, if at all, can we expose a [view/view-model component](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/creating-components/1) from a plugin? For instance, we have the following:

```
// ./open-id/foo-bar.html
<template>
    <p>FooBar</p>
</template>

// ./open-id/foo-bar.ts
export class FooBar { }
```

In the consuming application, we would like to do this:

```
// ./app.html
<require from="open-id/foo-bar"></require>
<foo-bar></foo-bar>
```

## Edits

#### Simpler Name

Based on Robinson Collado's answer, we using a simpler name (`foo` not `foo-bar`) to reduce complexity.

```
// ./open-id/foo.html
<template>
    <p>Foo</p>
</template>

// ./open-id/foo.ts
export class Foo { }

// ./app.html
<require from="open-id/foo"></require>
<foo></foo>
```

That approach threw this error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Load timeout for modules: template-registry-entry!open-id/foo.html,text!open-id/foo.html

#### Global Resource

Based on the [Installing Plugins](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/7) documentations, we tried adding the component as a global resource.

```
// ./open-id/open-id.ts
function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration) {
    config.globalResources('./foo');
}
```

That approach threw this error:

> GET http://localhost:9000/src/open-id/open-id/foo.js 404 (Not Found)

That means Aurelia is looking for the component in `open-id/open-id/`, which is one directory too deep.

#### Loading as a Plugin

During development of the plugin, we're loading the plugin like this, which may be why Aurelia is looking one directory too deep. How can we load the plugin differently during developent?

```
// ./main.ts
aurelia.use.plugin("./open-id/open-id");
```

#### Loading as a Feature

```
aurelia.use.feature("./aurelia-open-id-connect");
```

The error now is this for each constructor that receiving an injection from our feature.

> Message: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name of the custom tag `<foo-bar></foo-bar>` to `<foobar></foobar>`. The name of the tag should match the name of it's view-model class. Unless, if you use the @customElement decorator to explicitly declare the tag name for the custom element.

Comment: Sure. That makes sense. Also, what about using `config.globalResources('./foo-bar')`? That is throwing an error too.

Comment: Also, the solution that you are suggestion is giving the following error: "Load timeout for modules: template-registry-entry!open-id/foo-bar.html,text!open-id/foo-bar.html"

Comment: You can remove the index.js for the foo-bar custom element and put `aurelia.use.globalResources('./foo-bar)` in main.js. Then, you can remove all `<require from='./foo-bar'></require>` since the resources is made global.

Comment: I updated my answer with an attempt like that. I'm afraid it didn't work to configure the global resource.

Comment: Thank you for the help... it now works. In the bundling, we needed to change `"source": [ "**/src/open-id/*.js" ]` to `"source": [ "**/src/open-id/*.{js,html}" ]`. We can now require the component but we still cannot add it as a global resource.